# How to auto focus on an element that's not an input using only html

Tags: html

I am using the codes below but it's not auto-focusing on h4 upon page load. All content is visible by vertical scroll because of lorem1000 which ensures that I know if autofocus works

```html
     <body>
      <h1>text 1</h1>
      <p>lorem1000</p>
      <h2>text 1</h2>
      <p>lorem1000</p>
      <h3>text 1</h3>
      <p>lorem1000</p>
      <h4 name="focushere" autofocus>text 1</h4>
      <p>lorem1000</p>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to set the id/class of the H4 to ***focushere***, and then go to ***yoururl.com#focushere***.

To make it scroll smoothly when you open the page add this to your CSS:

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: If it's not an HTML-only feature then I can make use of other methods. I wanted to achieve the result via only HTML.

Comment: @AtmanAtos I do not know if there is a way to do it using pure HTML, the best way would be to inline some Javascript/JQuery

Comment: I understand that is an alternative

Comment: @AtmanAtos That **is** a HTML-only method.

Comment: @Rob, it only works when I manually type the #focushere to the end of the URL. <body><p>lorem1000</p><br><p id="focushere>lorem500</p></body> CSS= html{scroll-behaviour: smooth} . It's saved locally as Desktop/folder/auto focus on any element when page loads%23focushere.html Visiting this URL doesn't make it work, only when #focushere is added to the URL after the page loads.